# Angular5 and google reCAPTCHA2

Tags: angular, recaptcha

When I'm using reCAPTCHA2 in my Angular project, I use the following code to generate a captcha box (I filled site key in ofcourse in my real site):

```
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mySiteKey"></div>
```

This gives us the captcha like this:

[image]

However when I click on another link (implemented with Angular routerLink) and then go back the original page the CAPTCHA has disappeared.

The problem is that when implementing the captcha with

```
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mySiteKey"></div>
```

Google does all kinds of requests to the google servers to make the checkbox appear. Does anyone know how I could possibly solve this or point me in the right direction.

If you need more info comment, thanks.

Comment: I use this npm package for recaptcha in angular [link](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha)

Comment: @MohammadDaliri Did you test in `Angular 6`

Comment: @core114 yes I did

Comment: @MohammadDaliri Thanks ,

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who a similar issue here is the solution:

Google adviced to put the following link in your html header section:

`<script src=\'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js\'></script>`

This now only gets executed when the page is loaded.
When we go to another component this link isn't reloaded.

We can fix it with the following directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appReCaptcha2]'
})
export class ReCaptcha2Directive implements OnInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment('<script src=\'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js\'></script>');
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(fragment);
  }

}
```

This creates the script on the fly and therefore we get a working reCAPTCHA. This is because now the script can load the resources from the google server necessary to render and load the reCAPTCHA

Be sure to put `appReCaptcha2` directives on your forms where your want your reCAPTCHA to appear with the `<div>` google provides you which looks like this:

`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your site key provided by google"></div>`